# How to set Amplify branch BasicAuthCredentials with Boto3? Docs say 'string' but need to set username and password

Tags: boto3, aws-amplify

Couldn't find it in the docs. enableBasicAuth parameter will be set to true, what to set basicAuthCredentials 'string' to? Already tried 'username|password' and 'username:password'.

```
response = client.create_branch(
    appId='string',
    branchName='string',
    description='string',
    stage='PRODUCTION'|'BETA'|'DEVELOPMENT'|'EXPERIMENTAL'|'PULL_REQUEST',
    framework='string',
    enableNotification=True|False,
    enableAutoBuild=True|False,
    environmentVariables={
        'string': 'string'
    },
    basicAuthCredentials='string',
    enableBasicAuth=True|False,
    tags={
        'string': 'string'
    },
    buildSpec='string',
    ttl='string',
    displayName='string',
    enablePullRequestPreview=True|False,
    pullRequestEnvironmentName='string',
    backendEnvironmentArn='string'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, explanation [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/basic-authentication/).

Code as follows:

```
creds = "username:password"
creds_ascii = creds.encode("ascii")
creds_base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(creds_ascii)
creds_base64_utf8 = creds_base64_bytes.decode("utf-8")
```

```
...
basicAuthCredentials=creds_base64_utf8,
...
```